# How can I identify all matching columns for two rows of data?

Tags: sql, comparison, row

Using Standard ANSI SQL, how does one return a list of columns which are matching for *two specific rows* of data? We don't know the names of the columns, only the table name and the ID (or other primary key) to pick out the two specific rows we wish to compare?

Let's say we have a table with a large number of columns for real estate listings. If I choose two specific rows like so:

```
SELECT * 
FROM listing_data 
WHERE mls_number IN ('111111', '222222')
```

How can I identify the names of all other columns which happen to match between these two particular rows?

For example, perhaps there is a column called 'school_district' and they both are in the same district. Or perhaps the two listings share the same street name, or the same listing agent, or all three of these.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would care about Standard SQL.  In general, every database differs from the standard, so "Standard SQL" is likely to run on no or very few databases without modification.

Answer (score 0):

To get column names you can select from information_schema.columns however that is a table of column names only and does not have any data. If you are trying to do a select * from tablex where select * from tabley where columnname = 'value'  then if it works at all unless your tables are small it may take hours to complete.  It is simple if you know your column names to form up a query. Do some research and practice query on your tables and you should get some insight.   You are unlikely to have address data in a name column so once you get familiar with your data you should be able to craft a simple query.

Comment: Thank you very much, but this is not my question. I want to characterize two specific rows of data with a function which returns a list of column name WHERE the two rows share an exact data match. Some of the tables I wish to examine have 450+ columns in them (!) and hundreds of thousands of rows. I'm pretty sure I don't have to JOIN the entire table against its entire self, only do something with the two specific rows.

Comment: Yes I definitely do not understand.  Are you looking for exact duplicate rows? Or just any duplicate columns.  finding the column names of any data duplicated in any other column.  So like if the name column had a George and the city column also had a George then you want the column names of city and name?

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me, sorry I am not expressing this well. Imagine a single row with your name and address and state and country. Imagine a second row with the same data for me. We are comparing two rows that we have retrieved by our ID#. I want to return a list of each column where you and I have precisely the same data. If we both live in Indiana, then the list will have the "state" column and the "country" column. If we happen to both live in Indianapolis, then the list will contain the "city" column, and so on.

Comment: as far as I know this is a recursive search for each value in every column against the whole column,  I think what you want is to start with the column and look for duplicates in each column however if you have 450 columns this will take you some time to write every statement.  you may want to us something like python, to write them for you and use the information_schema.columns table to get all your column names.   in a database with thousands of rows and hundreds of columns this will occupy the computer for some time. consider narrowing down the list of possible columns,

Comment: the general method for finding duplicates in a column is  Select columNname from tablenName group by columNname having count > 1,, after that you can do with it what you want, but I do not know a way if you do not start with checking each column for duplicates

Comment: if you dont know column names try:  select * from tablename limit 1;  This will work on the information_schema table also and then you should see what columns you need.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly do the comparison for each column.  One method is:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN ld1.col1 IS NOT DISTINCT FROM ld.col1 THEN 'col1;' ELSE '' END ||
        CASE WHEN ld1.col2 IS NOT DISTINCT FROM ld.col2 THEN 'col2;' ELSE '' END ||
        . . .
       ) as matches             
FROM listing_data ld1 JOIN
     listing_data ld2
     ON ld1.mls_number = '111111' AND
        ld2.mls_number = '222222'
```